# How do I use company-mode in some buffers and auto-complete-mode in others?

Tags: company-mode, auto-complete-mode, local-variables

My init.el loads company with `(global-company-mode)`. I want to make an exception for Javascript buffers, and instead use `auto-complete-mode` for that mode.

**Q:** I am struggling to find a way to unhook company mode for only a particular mode. How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to, though? Both `tern` and `ac-js2` have company-mode backends.

Comment: Ignorance, mostly. I don't have a good understanding of what a good emacs JS environment looks like.

Comment: this was quite helpful for setting up EIN since it does not offer a company backend

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'my-javascript-hook)

(defun my-javascript-hook ()
  (company-mode -1)
  (auto-complete-mode 1))
```